# Retrieve data from multiple tables returning null and not null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a query which needs to retrieve the latest prices for thousands of items; the thing is, I need two separate columns from two tables, to return null or not null values.

These two tables contain prices which are different from one another.
If I don't have a price in column A from table 1, it should return null, and column B from table 2 would return a value (if there's data).

I'm leaving below the latest "version" of the query I tried to run but again, to no avail; the data is incorrect, it returns the wrong prices.

```
    SELECT a.orderid,
           a.itemid,
           d.currency,
           d.itemcategory,
           a.originalprice,
           c.companyid,
           b.price1,
           e.price2,
           Max(b.date) AS date,
           c.companycategory
    FROM   orders AS a
           INNER JOIN companydata AS b
                   ON a.itemid = b.itemid
           INNER JOIN companycodes AS c
                   ON a.orderid = c.orderid
           INNER JOIN orderoverview AS d
                   ON a.orderid = d.orderid
           INNER JOIN pricingdata AS e
                   ON a.sku = e.sku
    WHERE  a.orderid = '123456'
    GROUP  BY a.orderid,
              a.itemid,
              d.currency,
              d.itemcategory,
              a.originalprice,
              c.companyid,
              b.price1,
              e.price2,
              c.companycategory
```

It doesn't even return the latest pricing data for an item.
I am not sure if I should've used different types of joins but I spent the entire day googling and trying stuff.

The tables containing the prices are pricingdata (e) and companydata (b); if there are no prices for the companies the orders were created, they should return null values.

So far this query returned horrific results, and I tried using CASE but it won't work for checking multiple items at once; I will search for these prices by the orderid which may contain thousands of items.

Temps were my first attempt then I started questioning if I really need them so I gave up.

I also tried using while loops but...failed miserably x2.

I read about cursors but I don't think they apply here.

If it wasn't obvious by my first world problems, I'm a beginner.

Any help is highly appreciated and I thank you all in advance!

L.E. tried Dale's K advice and managed to enter the data here [SQL Fidler test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec297d/2/0)

By "incorrect prices" I mean it ignores the max(date) and somehow brings prices from other items/companies.

The output should bring the latest price per item, company and supplier. If there's data missing for the company/supplier, the cell should be populated with NULL.

Thank you once more!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results that illustrate the various edge cases. Ideally provide said sample data as DDL+DML so we can run your query directly against it without having to type it all in ourselves.

Comment: When you find yourself grouping by every column you can usually benefit from pre-aggregating or using an `apply`; note your query would be a lot easier to read with *meaningful* aliases, using a, b, c etc is not helpful. Sample data is needed to understand your issue.

Comment: What do you mean it returns the wrong prices? Is the price for widget not what you see in your table? Is the row for widget still in table A, just with a null price?

Comment: Sounds like the [Grouping pitfall](https://wikido.isoftdata.com/index.php/The_GROUPing_pitfall) problem. (first saw it mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69991331/4003419) post)

Comment: I think you need to update your query with "Order by date" after where clause.

Comment: show data and show expected output

Comment: @DaleK I just edited the post and I hope it now contains everything you needed. Big thank you!

Comment: Still no desired results... we need to see the output you are trying to achieve (you need to work it out manually).